# In React Native change not affect on real device

Tags: android, react-native

I am new in **React Native**. My environment is windows-10. I have created a simple project, it runs android emulator and real device successfully.

If i change something in App.js and build it into real device i don't see any changes, but i can see changes in my emulator.

**Can anybody tell me what should i do, to see my change in real device ?** I cleaned project and built it again in real device, but it doesn't change it shows the previous output.

I also tried it to uninstall app and execute below commands :

```
npm run start
react-native run-android
```

But it shows :
[image]

Comment: You might be installing an older build of the app.

Comment: run `npm start` and `react-native run-android`. this creates a debug apk in `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`. install this apk with `adb install <path to apk>` and check if it's updated.

Comment: @Shadow_m2 I executer this command it shows :`app-debug.apk: 1 file pushed. 3.8 MB/s (8141405 bytes in 2.055s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Success`. But output doesn't change.

Comment: I think i got the issue,  it's my device problem. Because it works fine for another device.